# Fetching the data from second api based on the response from the first api React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I was planning to call the second api using the data from the first api in my react project i tried using a single useState and chain the promises using axios but it isn't seems to be working as i want to basically filter out the data from the second api based on the first api id value

Api 1

```
[{
    id: 01,
    title: Post title One,
    external_id: 101
},
{
    id: 02,
    title: Post title Two,
    external_id: 102
},
{
    id: 03,
    title: Post title Three,
    external_id: 103
}]
```

Api 2

```
[{
    id: 101,
    image: Image Url,
},
{
    id: 102,
    image: Image Url,
},
{
    id: 103,
    image: Image Url,
}]
```

I want them to work side by side and then pass them as props to render items based on the data from both the APIs. Here is what i tried i know this code is not correct but i got stuck here. Here is my React code

```
const App = () => {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [postsExternal, setPostsExternal] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/posts`)
    .then(response => {
        setPosts(response.data);
        return response.data.external_id;
    })
    .then(getExternalId => axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/posts/${getExternalId}`))
    .then(response => {
        setPostsExternal(response.data);
    }), []);


    return (
        <div>
            <Posts posts={posts} postsExternal={postsExternal}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read your code and the problem is a little misplaced arrangement of your code. Also because you're getting an array of data and you'd need to make calls using the external_id for every data in that array

I'd suggest you try a different approach. Try the code snippet below (comments included to be better understood):

Thank you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";



const YourApp = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [postsExternal, setPostsExternal] = useState([]);

 
  useEffect(() => {
    // not adding .catch() here for simplicity 

    axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/posts`).then(({ data }) => {
      // we're putting this here because we only want to set state once (we don't wanna have to rerender 30times in data.map())
      let externalPosts = [];
      // destructed out the {data}, same as response.data, so no worries 
      setPosts(data);
      console.log(data);
      // this is where you'll make your second API calls using the external_id from first call
      data.map(({ external_id }) => {
        // {external_id} same as your-param-name.external_id
        axios
          .get(`http://localhost:2000/posts/${external_id}`)
          .then(({ data }) => {
            // we push the data into the array 
            console.log(data);
            externalPosts.push(data);
          });

        // then finally set the external post states once to prevent multiple rerendring in .map() 
        setPostsExternal(externalPosts);
        // that's it 
      });
    });

    // tho, i'd recommend you create a seperate function for the above 
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Posts posts={posts} postsExternal={postsExternal} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourApp;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch this solved my problem i was struggling to find the right output i'm still on the learning process.

Comment: but there is one problem since i am passing two props how to map them in a single component

Comment: Hi. Okay, you can spread the arrays (props) into a single array. But that would mean rendering both the initial "Posts" and the "externalPosts". You can do this by creating a variable (array) in your <Posts/> component. Then, spreading the properties (props) into the variable e.g `myVariable.push(...posts, ...externalPosts)` then you can now myVariable.map(render your element here)

Comment: Hey @Emmaccen i don't understand why this is not working when i reverse the apis the problem is that now the first api returns object of arrays and the second array of objects the code now returns an empty array of arrays for some reason here is the code https://pastebin.com/embed_js/C9mYwMRx

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an array not an individual object. Modify the `useEffect` to call the APIs using `Promise.all()` :

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/posts`)
    .then(response => {
        setPosts(response.data);
        return response.data.map(({external_id}) => external_id);
    })
    .then(externalIds => {
     return Promise.all(externalIds
                   .map(externalId => axios.get(`http://localhost:2000/posts/${externalId}`)))
    })
    .then(response => {
        setPostsExternal(response.data);
    }), 
}, []);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but the above code did not work for me it just wouldn’t  render anything even after fixing the typos in the above snipped so i hav accepted Emmaccen code